# How to disable default console logs from AudioEngine QML type

Tags: qt, audio, qml

I have used AudioEngine qml type to play some audio files in infinite loop and changing the pitch of audio based on some values using SoundInstance. Every time default console logs are printing continuously. Please help me to find the way to stop/disable console logs from AudioEngine qml type.

Please find some default logs below:

default openal device =  OpenAL Soft
device list:
OpenAL Soft

add QDeclarativeAudioSample[ "Tone" ]

add QDeclarativeAudioCategory[ "Volume" ]

add QDeclarativeSound[ "abc" ]

SoundCone: engine not changeable after initialization.

QDeclarativeSoundInstance::ctor()

QDeclarativeSoundInstance::setSound( "abc" )

Unknown child type for AudioEngine!

QDeclarativeSoundInstance::setEngine( QDeclarativeAudioEngine(0x5621e8471aa0) )

AudioEngine begin initialization

creating default category

init samples 1

creating new StaticSoundBufferOpenAL

init sounds 1

AudioEngine ready.

QDeclarativeSoundInstance::engineComplete()

QDeclarativeSoundInstance::setSound( "abc" )

SoundInstance switch sound from [ "" ] to [ "abc" ]

QDeclarativeSoundInstance::stop()

creating new QSoundInstance

QSoundInstance::bindSoundDescription QDeclarativeSound(0x7f4e90217970)

QAudioEnginePrivate::createSoundSource()

creating new QSoundSourcePrivate

QSoundInstance::prepareNewVariation()

QSoundInstance: generate new play variation [old: -1 , new: 0 - "spo2Tone" ]

QSoundInstance::updateVariationParameters 1 1 false

QDeclarativeAudioCategory[ "Volume" ] setVolume( 0.8 )

StaticSoundBufferOpenAL:sample[ QUrl("qrc:/Audio/xyz.wav") ] loaded

QSoundInstance::bufferReady()

QDeclarativeSoundInstance::stop()

QSoundInstancePrivate::play()

QSoundInstance::prepareNewVariation()
QDeclarativeSoundInstance::play()
........

Please find below my sample code:

```
 AudioEngine {
        id: audioengine

        AudioSample {
            name: "Tone"
            source: "qrc:/Audio/abc.wav"
        }

        AudioCategory {
            name: "Volume"
            volume: 100
        }

        Sound {
            name: "abc"
            playType: Sound.Random
            category: "Volume"

            PlayVariation {
                sample:"Tone"
            }
        }

        SoundInstance {
            id: soundEffect
            engine: audioengine
            sound: "abc"
        }
    }
    
    Connections {
    target: viewModel
    function onSignalEmited() {
        if(viewModel.xyz)
        {
            soundEffect.play();
        }
        else {
            soundEffect.stop();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does it do that even if you build in Release mode?

Comment: Yes, it is displaying default console logs in release mode as well.